# String encoding in string instances from different languages

Tags: character-encoding

I recently got a requirement to develop a chat-like application, or rather, a foundation of classes and methods that would allow certain applications to have chat-like features. The framework must be usable in at least two languages: Visual Basic 6 and C#.

If `VB6-Application A` were to transmit string data to `CSharp-Application B`, when the data is received by `CSharp-Application B` and placed into a `string`, can I assume the string will contain the same information it contained when `VB6-Application A` sent it? (i.e. it will contain the same sequence of bytes that was sent from the original string instance in the VB6 app.)

Comment: Depends entirely on A) what encoding it expects to send/receive and B) what encoding it transforms the received message/message to send.  Aside from this, there shouldn't be any changes in the byte-per-byte information sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing @Neil's comment, you have to make sure the encoding is the same on the sending/receiving ends. Assuming that you can pass a byte array from one language to the other, you will want to think about what encoding to use. UTF-8 is likely the most popular now. If you're not familiar with character encodings, please take a brief moment to check out the [basics, courtesy of Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Doing a little research, it sounds like VB6 stores strings internally as UTF-16 but tends to convert to ANSI for the outside world. So an approach you could take on the VB side for conversions between UTF-8 and byte arrays is found [here](http://paulturner.me/2008/09/visual-basic-6-activex-and-unicode/). The C# side is a little less convoluted and you can find an MSDN page with nice code samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I had to put this requirement on hold for a while. I will be working on it now, and the first and second articles were very very instructive. Thanks!